# How to run background task? keep getting System.AggregateException

Tags: c#, background-service, ihostedservice

This is my program.cs

```
using TestEmailTaskScheduler.Controllers;
using TestEmailTaskScheduler.Models;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<EmailService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<EmailService>();
builder.Configuration.GetSection("DailyEmail").Get<MySettingsModel>();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And this is a part of the test code in my controller service:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using TestEmailTaskScheduler.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TestEmailTaskScheduler.Controllers
{
    public class EmailService : BackgroundService
    {
        private const int generalDelay = 1 * 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds
        private readonly IOptions<MySettingsModel> appSettings;
        private readonly IOptions<MyDatabaseModel> databaseSettings;
        private Timer Schedular;

    public EmailService(IOptions<MySettingsModel> app)
    {
        appSettings = app;
    }
    public EmailService(IOptions<MyDatabaseModel> dbs)
    {
        databaseSettings = dbs!;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(generalDelay, stoppingToken);
            await DoBackupAsync();
        }
    }

    private Task DoBackupAsync()
    {
        // here i can write logic for taking backup at midnight
        if (IsMidnight())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing background task");
            //SendEmail();
        }

        return Task.FromResult("Done");
    }
```

> Error: System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: TestEmailTaskScheduler.Controllers.EmailService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: TestEmailTaskScheduler.Controllers.EmailService': Unable to activate type 'TestEmailTaskScheduler.Controllers.EmailService'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
> Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[TestEmailTaskScheduler.Models.MySettingsModel]) Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[TestEmailTaskScheduler.Models.MyDatabaseModel])) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: TestEmailTaskScheduler.Controllers.EmailService': Unable to activate type 'TestEmailTaskScheduler.Controllers.EmailService'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
> Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[TestEmailTaskScheduler.Models.MySettingsModel]) Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[TestEmailTaskScheduler.Models.MyDatabaseModel]))'

Why is this happening? I thought it is already called in the program.cs?

Comment: For DI to work properly, you need to have exactly one constructor. eg `EmailService(IOptions<MySettingsModel> app, IOptions<MyDatabaseModel> dbs){...}`

Comment: Check your appsettings.json. It is likely that it does not have the section named "DailyEmail". You are also using the contructor incorrectly. Simply use MyDatabaseModel (instead of IOptions<MyDatabaseModel> ) if you are directly using Get<T> on options config.

Comment: I followed what @JeremyLakeman and it started running, but now the error is that the appsetting value is null, although it is taking it from the appsettings.json 'DailyEmail'. the DailyEmail is there, but I dont know why the value is null

Comment: `.GetSection("DailyEmail").Get<MySettingsModel>()` will return the config object. What you want is `.Configure<MySettingsModel>(....GetSection("DailyEmail"))` which you should see in other examples / tutorials.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I did this code before "builder.Services.Configure<MySettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("DailyEmail"));" but i get this error cs0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member' for the 'Configuration.GetSection' part

Comment: nvm got it working just needed to add 'builder' at "builder.Services.Configure<MySettingsModel>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DailyEmail"));"